# How to set Absolute paths that are constant throughout

Tags: php, path

I have a `paths.php` in my root folder which I'm hoping will help using paths simpler. I set the root to

```
$server = dirname(__DIR__) . "\projectfolder";
if(!defined('ROOT')) {define('ROOT', dirname($server));}
```

This setup seems to work fine until I get deeper into the folder, for example `projectfolder/includes/file.php` and I try to call a stylesheet or other static files with the root constant. I did a var_dump and I see it returning '.'

Why is that? I've also seen that `includes/` becomes the new root for that file. How can I set my project up so that the root will be absolute throughout the project?

P.S. I tried other methods such as `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, etc., but I mostly see the same problems.

P.P.S. This is what I had at first using 'SERVER_NAME':

```
if(!defined('ROOT'))
{
     define('ROOT',dirname(dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using
`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` you can get the root folder. Then if you have your config for example one folder above, you can use

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../config.php"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This only work if the scripts are running via an HTTP server and only then, one that populates the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` environment variable

Comment: Ok I followed your way and now when I'm trying to access static files it gives this error: "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/..."

Just for reference, I have this in place of my head tag: `<?php include(ROOT.'includes/head-tag.php'); ?>`. However, in head-tag.php, I have these in place of relative paths: `<link href=<?php echo CSS."/main.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">
  <link href=<?php echo CSS."/bootstrap.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Where does it tell you that error? Can you provide an example?